# Button works only click twice when I use

Tags: android, multithreading, jsoup

I want my button to work when I click it once. However, it only works if I click it twice.

I think this problem is related with Jsoup or Thread because when I removed the Jsoup method, it worked properly.

Of course, I have added Jsoup Library.

Here is my code:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    String word = editText.getText().toString();
                    try {
                        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=kr&searchOption=all&query="+word).get();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }

                    Elements el = doc.getElementsByClass("fnt_e30");

                    if(el.size() == 0){
                        s="There is no result.";
                        return;
                    }
                    s="OK";
                }
            }.start();
            textView.setText(s);
        }
    };
    btn_search.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: The reason is Its an Asynchronous call ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that by 'works' you mean to say that the `TextView` get's set with the text "OK". In which case, your code is running properly, you have the `s="OK";` running on a separate thread. Only after that value get's set will `textView.setText(s);` run as you expect it to. You'll probably want to do something along the following lines instead.

```
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    String word = editText.getText().toString();
                    try {
                        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=kr&searchOption=all&query="+word).get();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }

                    Elements el = doc.getElementsByClass("fnt_e30");

                    if(el.size() == 0){
                        s="There is no result.";
                        return;
                    }
                    s="OK";
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText(s);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }.start();
        }
    };
    btn_search.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

P.S - As mentioned by ADM in the comments, it's an asynchronous call (since it's done on a thread), `Jsoup.connect` will take time to connect and get the doc. You should preferably deactivate the button after it's clicked once (basically indicate to the user that the request is being handled and ask them to wait for the result).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it on wrong way. You are listening response and set in variable as well but not setting into the textview.

**Why its happening second time?** When you click first time code of setText will be executed but that will not having any value.

Right Approach. Add this code after you setting in value in **s** variable.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText(s);
    }
});
```